# IE 11 not compatible with RicoLive Grid 2.2 FrameWork

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, internet-explorer

Previously we are using ricolivegrid which is compatible with till Ie9 or chrome but now my organisation is moved to Ie 11 /edge. now ricolivegrid stop working looks like its a compatiblity issue. any suggestion which  need to make in either rico library or java script else anything to do with IE11 please suggest its very important

i am using RicoLiveGrid 2.2 
http://openrico.sourceforge.net/examples/LiveGrid.html

Vikas Kumar

Answer (score -1):

I have just hit the same issue. I found an exception thrown in Prototype library `setRequestHeaders` function.

A header name causes the exception.

```
 extend value:function(object){ return Object.extend.apply(this, [this, object]);}
```

I have worked around it by wrapping `this.transport.setRequestHeader` in a try catch block i.e.:

```
for (var name in headers)
{
      try
      {
          this.transport.setRequestHeader(name, headers[name]);
      }
      catch (ex){}
}
```

Absence of the erroneous header doesn't appear to have any impact on the functionality of the grid.